# How does one track a data pipeline with MLflow?

Tags: mlflow

I'm working on a machine learning system that has a fairly complex data preparation pipeline with several steps that needs to be run before getting to the machine-learning part of the problem. Based on MLflow's documentation, I was expecting to be able to use MLflow Tracking to keep track of how a particular data set was prepared. I feel like this use case is implied by MLflow's documentation, but it isn't explicitly mentioned. For example, the "AI Workflows and Personas" figure in [What is MLflow?](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/what-is-mlflow.html) includes "Data Preparation" as step 0. What is the expected usage pattern to track data through step 0?

My first surprise was that `mlflow.data` does not have any Dataset that represents an arbitrary file on disk; the assumption seems to be that data is always represented as a NumPy array with more or less decoration. This wasn't too difficult to overcome; I simply wrote a `FilesystemDataset` (to go along with the `FileystemDatasetSource`) that represents a path to a file.

I annotated the first step of the process with `mlflow.log_input` and `mlflow.log_artifact` calls and didn't run into any problems. Then I annotated the second step, and this is where the problems begin.

The second step of the process takes the output of the first step as an input (as you might expect). I used a `runs:/<run_id>/<artifact_path>` URI to specify the input. I can fetch the artifact from the store without a problem. However, using that exact same URI as a "raw" source to the `source` keyword argument of `from_filesystem` (which is analagous to [`from_numpy`](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.data.html#mlflow.data.from_numpy)) and is described like this:

> The source from which the filesystem data was derived, e.g. a filesystem path, an S3 URI, an HTTPS URL, a delta table name with version, or spark table etc. source may be specified as a URI, a path-like string, or an instance of DatasetSource. If unspecified, the source is assumed to be the code location (e.g. notebook cell, script, etc.) where from_filesystem is being called.

I get an error stating "Could not find a source information resolver for the specified dataset source: runs:/...". I found out that `register_artifact_dataset_sources` [explicitly excludes](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/1911991fc885aadd04fe72bebadb4c311ad5c148/mlflow/data/artifact_dataset_sources.py#L19-L32) the `runs` scheme (along with several others).

I modified my code to create a `RunsDatasetSource` anyway, and it works, but there's no linkage in the MLflow UI between the input of the second step and the artifact of the first step. Is there a way to get MLflow to be really aware of this artifact-as-input relationship?